# pyomo solvers in Anaconda (different results than commandline)

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I'm running the rosenbrock.py example from page 64 of the PDF at https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1376827`, which is similar to pyomo_examples\doc\pyomobook\nonlinear-ch\rosen

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var(initialize=-1.2, bounds=(-2, 2))
model.y = Var(initialize=1.0, bounds=(-2, 2))
model.obj = Objective(expr=(1-model.x)**2 + 
100*(model.y-model.x**2)**2,sense=minimize)
```

I'm using Anaconda with Python 3.6 under Windows 10 64-bit and I have GLPK and IPOPT installed in the path (IPOPT is part of the SolverStudio installation).  I can run the example from the command line and I get the following abbreivated result:

```
>pyomo solve rosen.py --solver=ipopt --summary
Number of solutions: 1
Solution Information
Gap: None
Status: optimal
Function Value: 2.9895642187051186e-17
Solution Summary
Variables:
x : Value: 0.9999999945428673
y : Value: 0.9999999890517721
Objectives: Value: 2.9895642187051186e-17
Constraints:  None
```

If I then run this same model within IPython/Anaconda, using SolverFacotry:

```
opt = SolverFactory("ipopt",  executable=
"E:\\SolverStudio\\SolverStudio\\Solvers\\64bit\\ipopt.exe")
results = opt.solve(model)
print(results)
```

I get a result with "Termination condition: optimal", but the solution says "number of solutions: 0".

```
Problem: 
Lower bound: -inf
Upper bound: inf
Number of objectives: 1
Number of constraints: 0
Number of variables: 2
Sense: unknown
Solver: 
Status: ok
Message: Ipopt 3.12.1\x3a Optimal Solution Found
Termination condition: optimal
Id: 0
Error rc: 0
Time: 0.5311787128448486
Solution: 
number of solutions: 0
number of solutions displayed: 0
```

The result says the problem is not bounded and the sense is unknow. Can I use the same model within Pythan that I use from the commandline, of do I need to change it somehow?  I'd expect to use the same Python script for both the commandline and within IPython/Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

The `pyomo` command does some extra stuff to output the results in a human readable form. The basic steps are:

1. build the model
2. call the solve (results are automatically loaded)
3. extract the solution from the model using human-readable names
4. print the results

In step 2, "results are automatically loaded" means the solution object stored on the results object is taken off and loaded into the model. This leads to the confusing "number of solutions: 0" output when you print the results object in a script.

If you want Pyomo to leave the solution object on the results object, you should pass `load_solutions=False` to the solve method. Then, after checking statuses and verifying that the results object contains a solution (`len(results.solution) > 0`), you can manually load the solution into the model with `model.solutions.load_from(results)`.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the reply